# How do I find a non-trivial 2D representation of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \subset $ SL(2, $\mathbb{C}$)?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am trying to find a non-trivial two dimensional representation of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \subset SL(2, \mathbb{C})$, but I am a little stuck.

Here is what I did so far:

For M $\in$ SL(2, $\mathbb{Z}_2$):
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}
with det M = ad - bc = 1 and a, b, c, d $\in$ {0, 1}.

I also found that the order of SL(2, $\mathbb{Z}_2$) is 6.

So putting the pieces together, I think that this means that I am looking for a representation of six 2 x 2 matrices that each have a determinant of +1, where my matrix elements are either 0 or 1.

I found the following 3 matrices that satisfy these conditions
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}

This is where I am stuck: I am unable to find 3 more matrices, only consisting of 0 and 1, that satisfy the condition that my determinant is 1. How do I proceed?

Comment: This is extremely confusing to me. What subgroup of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$ are you talking about? Why are you calling that subgroup $Z_2$ when you're *also* using $Z_2$ for the integers mod $2$? Why are you using $Z_2$ to refer to two different things? Wouldn't this subgroup of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$ *already* have a 2D rep since it's *already made up of $2\times2$ matrices*? And what do matrices over integers mod $2$ have to do with any of this??

Comment: The subgroup of SL(2, $\mathbb{C}$) is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. So the $Z_2$ was referring to the same thing, i.e. to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (I have edited it in the question, sorry for the confusion!)

Comment: Can you just be clear about what $Z_2$ is? To me, it's comprised of $0$ and $1$ mod $2$. These are residues (or more formally, cosets of $2\Bbb Z$ within $\Bbb Z$), they are not elements of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$, which is comprised of matrices not numbers or residues. Since $\Bbb Z_2$ is not a subset of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$, it certainly can't be a subgroup! Are you *identifying* $Z_2$ with an isomorphic subgroup of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$, and if so which one? And **again**, what does $SL(2,\Bbb Z_2)$ have to do with anything at all!?!?

Comment: ''Find a nontrivial 2D representation of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \subset$ SL(2, C)'' is how the question is stated in my book. I am also confused about the wording, and not sure what the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is referring to. I (apparently wrongfully) assumed that it must be referring to the set of integers mod 2, as I had no idea what else it could be referring to. The reason why I wrote SL(2, $\mathbb{Z}_2$) is because I didn't know how else to implement the $\mathbb{Z}_2 \subset SL(2, C)$ statement.

Comment: What book? You didn't mention any book. Maybe it's asking you to find a representation $\Bbb Z_2\to SL(2,\Bbb C)$. That makes more sense than *starting* with $Z_2$ already made up of $2\times2$ matrices, since then it's *already* a 2D representation! And as far as I can tell, $SL(2,\Bbb Z_2)$ has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with this problem, it's actually bizarre seeing it brought up.

Comment: I see! Assuming that that is indeed what it is asking for then, could you perhaps guide me on how to solve it, as I clearly completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: You want to exhibit a homomorphism $\Bbb Z_2\to SL(2,\Bbb C)$. The identity element $0\in\Bbb Z_2$ must be sent to the identity element $I_2\in SL(2,\Bbb C)$. So it only remains to see where $1\in\Bbb Z_2$ can be sent. Since $1$ has order two in $\Bbb Z_2$, it must be sent to an element in $SL(2,\Bbb C)$ of order two. Can you find such an element?